# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1). Facing a issue while converting string to int

Tags: flutter

I am facing an issue when I am trying to convert string to int. I have fetched the data successfully from the world time api but when I am converting offset to string and adding it, the code runs successfully but not showing data on console.

The error in console is:

[image]

And the code for the above error is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this error because indeed **05:30** is not a number!
what you need to do it split the hours from the minutes, parse them individually and the create the duration object from the values you have,

```
final time = offset.toString();
final hours = time.split(':').first;
final minutes = time.split(':').last;
now = now.add(Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am facing another issue working on the same project and the issue is :- Field 'time' should be initialized because its type 'String' doesn't allow null. Will you pls help me in this also ... i have also initialised in the async function.. that is time = now.toString(); , but it gives me the error while i am creating a constructor.

Comment: Show me the code so i can tell where is the error

Comment: here is the code :-                                                      String location; // location name for UI
  String time;// the time in that location
  String flag; // url to an asset flag icon
  String url;

  WorldTime({ required this.location, required this.flag, required this.url });                                                I haved initialised the time in async function but still it's showing that it can not be used as null charater                         time = now.toString(); like this

Comment: beautiful, can you show where do **initialize** the time? and where do you use it?
if you use inside a method and initialize it in a method, please show me the methods invokes

Comment: here is the method where i initialised :-     Future<void> getTime() async {

    // make the request
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse('http://www.worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    //print(data);

    // get properties from the data
    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);

    // create a DateTime object
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));


    // set the time property
     time = now.toString();

Comment: and here i used it to desplay the time on screen :-  class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {

  String time = 'loading';

  void setupWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime instance = WorldTime(location: 'India', flag: 'india.png', url: 'Asis/Kolkata');
    await instance.getTime();
    print(instance.time);
    setState(() {
      time = instance.time;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupWorldTime();
  }

Comment: @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        child: Text(time),
      ),
    );
  }
}